# 'or' and 'and' in same if statement

Tags: python

I am wondering why this returns true:

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  if hour < 7 or hour > 20 and talking == True:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(parrot_trouble(False, 6))
```

Is it because you can't have 'or' and 'and' operators in same if statement? Or other reason?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  This is explained in the language rules on operator precedence, and any tutorial on Boolean expressions.  We expect you to do your research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about the operator's precedence
[image]
In order to make that work you will need to specify the order of operators with parantheses.

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  if (hour < 7 or hour > 20) and talking == True:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(parrot_trouble(False, 6))
```

What is in parantheses will be executed first and then compared to `and`.

Comment: Please provide the source, if you use material from outside, makes it easier for OP for further research

Comment: Would you mind please providing some context to the table, or a reference link?  Thank you.

Comment: https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Comment: Sorry but no. I have it in my computer from a long time ago and I don't know the source anymore, but feel free to search for Python operator precedence maybe you will find it.

Answer (score 4):

This is, because `AND` has priority over `OR`, so you have

`TRUE OR (FALSE AND FALSE)` resulting in `TRUE`

The extensive list of `Operator Precedence` can be found [here](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Evalerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html):

Most importantly are
`() > not > and > or >`

So to give priority to your `OR operator` use `()`

```
(hour < 7 or hour > 20) and talking == True 
=> (TRUE OR FALSE) AND FALSE => FALSE
```

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

To give some more background to the already posted answer:

This is based on operator precedence as explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

The higher the precedence the stronger it binds its two parts. You can image that like addition and multiplication in maths. There, multiplications bind stronger. Here, the and binds stronger as written in a different answer.